Flags used during compilation
I am compiling huge C code base, And we are using Make build system to automate the build process. Basically we use lot of flags which are scattered across multiple make files and those compiler flags are being used to compile .C files. Is there a way to find what all compiler flags are being used to compile to .C source files once after completion of build?
Is there any tracing mechanism exists to find what all flags are being used for compiling and linking? Basically i want to store metadata of a build like compiler flags,linker flags,exe and library file sizes...etc, I can easily find size of libs,exe. But i am stuck to find what flags are being used during compilation.

Unless prevented to do so make prints each recipe before it is executed by the shell. So, all your compilation commands shall be part of this output. Isn't it enough?

compiler command i huge , Here i want to basically get all flags being used and show it in UI for some metrics. People wont looks for build logs. Instead they want to view the list of flags being used via some UI.

So, what prevents you from processing the make standard output to extract what you need, format it as you need and show the result in your "UI"?

As mentioned in the comments, you should be able to process your output.   If you want something more structured however, one option is you can change the recipe:
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

to something like:
%.o: %.c
    echo '$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<' > $@.cmd
    echo 'compiling $< -> $@'
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

and then post-process the .cmd files.

Actually i have multiple rules where i want to use the same. Can we move echo '$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<' > $@.cmd to some define and call it whenever required? please help me with the syntax

The most direct answer to your question is "no, there is no database or historical log of operations that is maintained by make to track your builds".  If you want such a thing you will have to create it yourself; HardcoreHenry's answer gives one possible way to do this.
Another option, if you don't want to modify the makefile, would be to create a script or program that logs the command line it's passed, then invokes the shell to run it.  Suppose you call it logsh.  Then you can run make using:
make SHELL=/path/to/logsh

Be aware that it must accept the same command-line options as the shell (e.g., -c etc.)

Another, maybe simpler, solution in the same vein could be to hack CC with a script that logs its arguments before calling the real compiler with the same arguments.

Yes, if you just wanted to track the compiler options and not every command, that's probably simpler.
